# Adding TextBlock in ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I want to  add a `TextBlock` with text to my `DataTemplate` in my `ItemsControl` using `Caliburn micro`.

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="Images"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Height="180" Width="180" Margin="10">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Names}"/>
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="{Binding}" 
                            ViewboxUnits="RelativeToBoundingBox"    
                            local:ViewBoxTracking.Source="{Binding ElementName=MainImage}" />
                    </Grid.Background>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

My `C#` code from `ViewModel` class looks like this:

```
    public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Images { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<ImageSource>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Names { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    this.Names.Add("text1");
    this.Names.Add("text2");
    this.Names.Add("text3");
    this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Names);

    this.Images.Add(bmpimage1);
    this.Images.Add(bmpimage2);
    this.Images.Add(bmpimage3);
    this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Images);
```

From code above texts dont appear:

[image]

I want to attach `TextBlocks` programatically with `Images`. I want  it look like this:

[image]

How to add `Text` to `TextBlocks` from  `DataTemplate` from `ItemsControl` using `Caliburn.Micro`'s binding?

Comment: `Images` should return an `ObservableCollection<YourType>` where `YourType` has an `ImageSource` property *and* a `string` property. You should not use two different collections.

Comment: I need to make `Tuple` for it? Something like `ObservableCollection<ImageSource, 
 string>` ?

Comment: A class with two public properties. And an itemtemplate which has an image + textblock in a grid or stackpanel

Comment: Using a Tuple is not the usual approach. Far more common would be a dedicated item class with two or more properties with descriptive names. See the answer to the original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a single source collection. `Images` should return an `ObservableCollection<YourType>` where `YourType` has an `ImageSource` property *and* a `string` property. `YourType` may be a custom class or a `Tuple<string, ImageSource>`:

```
public ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, ImageSource>> Images { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, ImageSource>>();
...
this.Images.Add(Tuple.Create("text1", bmpimage1));
this.NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Images);
```

You can then bind to both properties in your `ItemTemplate`:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Item1}"/>
```

or

```
<TextBlock x:Name="Item1"/>
```

Comment: I dont know why someone  downvoted your answer, because it work. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Caliburn Micro then you should consider "buying in" to the convention based  binding mechanism.  https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/conventions

This will create bindings on the fly for you.

For named controls it looks for a property in the datacontext with a matching name and creates a binding on the default property of that control.

Textblock will be text and I think image is imagesource.

Hence a class with public properties is less code than a tuple. Because I don't think this will work with a tuple.

If you use an observablecollection of rowviewmodels where rowviewmodel is a class with public properties Img and Txt the following simplified markup:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Name="Img"/>
        <TextBlock Name="Txt"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

Should see both the image and textblock binding so long as you've implemented the expected parts of caliburn micro.

Similarly, the binding of itemssource of your collection.